# perl send internal array as argument to subroutine

Tags: perl

I have a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
$map[0][0] = 'a';
$map[0][1] = 'b';
$map[1][0] = 'c';
$map[1][1] = 'd';
```

I want to pass only everything under $map[1] (by reference) to a subroutine. How to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl doesn't have multiple dimension arrays.

What you have is an array and each element of that array is a *reference* to another array. You might want to read up about [Perl References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) since this is the way Perl allows you to build some very complex data structures.

Many people think of it as a multidimensional array, and you could treat it as such ***under certain circumstances***. However, I prefer the `->` syntax which reminds me that this is merely a reference to a reference.

```
$map[0]->[0] = 'a';
$map[0]->[1] = 'b';
$map[1]->[0] = 'c';
$map[1]->[1] = 'd';
```

Now, I can take the data structure apart:

- `@map`: This is an array with two items in it, `$map[0]` and `$map[1]`.
- `$map[0]->[]`: This is a *reference* to another array. That array also has to items in it.
- `$map[1]->[]`: This is another *reference* to yet another array. That array has two items in it.

Note that `$map[1]->[]` means that `$map[1]` contains an array reference. Thqt means you can pass `$map[1]` as your reference to that inner array.

```
mysub ($map[1]);
```

Here's a simple program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @map;
$map[0]->[0] = 'a';
$map[0]->[1] = 'b';
$map[1]->[0] = 'c';
$map[1]->[1] = 'd';

mysub( $map[1] );

sub mysub {
    my $array_ref = shift;

    my @array = @{ $array_ref };  # Dereference your reference

    for my $index ( 0..$#array ) {
        say "\$map[1]->[$index] = $array[$index]";
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
$map[1]->[0] = c
$map[1]->[1] = d
```

Now, you see why I like that `->` syntax although it's really completely unnecessary. It helps remind me what I am dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

You can send array reference,

```
sub mysub {
  my ($aref) = @_;

  # work with @$aref ..
}

mysub($map[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the scalar `$map[1]`.

```
fn($map[1]);

sub fn
{
    my @loc_map_1 = @{ $_[0] };
```

Remember that perl doesn't have "real" 2 dimensional arrays.  In your case `map` is an array that contains 2 references to arrays.